# How to initialize dataclass field with a copy of a list?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I'm parsing text files which have the following line structure:

> name_id, width, [others]

After parsing an input, I'm feeding each parsed line into the `dataclass`:

```py
@dataclass(frozen=True, eq=True)
class Node():
    name: str
    rate: int
    other: list[str] = field(compare = False)
```

In the middle of the code, I'm removing values from `other`, which results in removing values from original parse output. I don't want that. How can I make `dataclass` to force making a copy of the list?

In common class, as I understand, solution would be:

```py
self.other = other.copy()
```

But if doing so, I should rewrite whole `init` method which breaks the purpose of `dataclass`.

So how to initialize `dataclass` field with a copy of a list?

I've tried doing this:

```py
def __post_init__(self):
    setattr(self, 'other', self.other.copy())
```

Which yield can't assign attribute of frozen instance.

Comment: "So how to initialize dataclass field with a copy of a list?" - just pass it a copy of the list?

Comment: Sounds good,  @user2357112. But now I'm wondering is it possible to say dataclass to do so.

Comment: Add a class method `def from_copy(cls, *args, other, **kwargs): return cls(*args, other.copy(), **kwargs)`?

Comment: The main reason not to do this in `__init__` is that it makes an unnecessary copy if you do something like `Node("foo", 5, [1,2,3])`: nothing else can possibly have a reference to the new list that the list display creates, so there's no reason to make a copy of it. Use the class method to encapsulate making a copy when you *know* you need a copy.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO this is a bad idea and looks like breaking ["explicit is better than implicit" aphorisms](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/). But if you really want to you can <s>hack</s> force it with `object.__setattr__`:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True, eq=True)
class Node:
    name: str
    rate: int
    other: list[str] = field(compare=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'other', self.other.copy())
```

#### Explanation

`object.__setattr__` is the default python `__setatter__` while `__setattr__` uses class's `__setattr__` method which in the case of `dataclass` is overridden to ensure that user doesn't change the field of the frozen `dataclass` (so you skip the check).

Comment: Not sure it’s that bad an idea.  You feed data into class X.  OK. Do you expect class X to “reach out” and modify what you have?  Maybe, in some cases.  Not necessarily here.

Comment: @JLPeyret But this *is* modifying what you have as you make a copy of the thing you passed and now your object stores something different from what you passed to it (as python works with references). So changing the `other` list of the `Node` will not reflect in the list you initially passed. Again, this is my opinion and depends on the requirements.